# How to decompose a complex number into a sum of two unitary modulus complex numbers?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, nonlinear-system

Is it possible to decompose any complex number $z = x + iy\in \mathbb{C}$ with $0\leq|z|\leq2$ into a sum of two unitary modulus exponentials ? i.e. $ z = e^{i\phi_1} + e^{i\phi_2}$ ?

I tried to decompose the problem $x + iy = \cos(\phi_1) + \cos(\phi_2) + i(\sin(\phi_1) + \sin(\phi_2)) $ into a set of two real equations but is seems that they are not linear  :

\begin{eqnarray}
\cos(\phi_1) + \cos(\phi_2) & = &x \\
\sin(\phi_1) + \sin(\phi_2) & = & y
\end{eqnarray}

If it is possible, are there any known algorithm ? I tried the usual trigonometric transformations without success. And formulating the problem in terms of modulus and phase rather than real and imaginary parts made it seem more complex.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: [inverse kinematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_kinematics), a field which answers the question: given a robot arm with $N$ joints, how to rotate the joints such that the arm reaches a given point in space?

Comment: @KingTut The problem of finding two complex exponentials that sum to a given point in the complex plane is equivalent to moving a robot arm with two joints and two segments of length 1, in a plane, such that the end of this arm reaches a desired point. The algorithms of inverse kinematics will help find an answer, if one exists (which, post-edit, it probably does).

Comment: Yeah I figured that out, thats why I removed the comment. Looks interesting, if you have more to offer please do.

Comment: Wouter. Very interesting!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This document](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~ocj/courses/autorob/autorob_10_ik_closedform.pdf) contains a closed-form solution for a slightly more general version of this problem: find $\theta_1,\theta_2$ such that
$$\alpha_1\exp(i\theta_1) + \alpha_2\exp(i(\theta_2+\theta_1))=x+i y$$
with $\alpha_1,\alpha_2>0$ given, and $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=1$ in the context of this question.

The solution is
$$\theta_2=\arccos\left(\frac{x^2+y^2-\alpha_1^2-\alpha_2^2}{2\alpha_1\alpha_2}\right)$$
$$\theta_1=\arctan(x/y) - \arctan\left(\frac{\alpha_2\sin(\theta_2)}{\alpha_1+\alpha_2\cos(\theta_2)}\right)$$

Answer (score 5):

You can go like this:

first consider $z$ is a real number, let $\cos \theta = z/2$,so we have
$z = e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}$.

In general,let $z = re^{i\theta}$,and $r = e^{i\alpha} + e^{-i\alpha}$(As above).
Then $z = e^{i(\theta + \alpha)} + e^{i(\theta- \alpha)}$

Comment: Great! Concise and amazing

Comment: As a geometric intuition for this answer - we are looking for an isosceles triangle with sides of length 1,1 and r. The base angle for such a triangle satisfies $\theta=\arccos r/2$, and with a bit of sketching you can see the angles for the sides are indeed $\alpha \pm \theta$

Answer (score 5):

The perpendicular bisector  of the segment connecting $z$ with $0$  intersects the unit circle in two points $e^{i\theta_1}$, $e^{i\theta_2}$ satisfying $e^{i\theta_1}+e^{i\theta_2}=z$.

Answer (score 1):

No. it is not, because$$\left|e^{i\phi_1}+e^{i\phi_2}\right|\leqslant1+1=2.$$

Comment: he has played the edit game.

Comment: so ? the problem was not resolvable in general, but with modulus constraint it seems that it is

Comment: @Red - José Carlos Santos answered "No" when it is evident that the answer is now "yes". King Tut is pointing out that José Carlos Santos was actually correct for the question he was answering and the reason for the disconnect is that the question has changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically, it is perfectly possible: in the *Argand-Cauchy* plane, consider the image $M$ of $z$: $0\le OM=r\le 2$, and the intersections 
$I$ and $J$ of the circle of radius $OM$, centred at $M$. Elementary geometry shows that intersection points exist because$M$ is at distance $ \le 1$ from the unit circle, the quadrilateral $OIMJ$ is a rhombus and
$$\overrightarrow{OM}=\overrightarrow{OI}+\overrightarrow{OJ}.$$
If $z_I, z_J$ are the affixes of these points, this vector relation translates as $\;z=z_I+z_J$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's derive the solution ourselves. Given $z = x + iy$ we search for two imaginary numbers $\rho_1, \rho_2$ such that $|\rho_1| = |\rho_2| = 1$ and $\rho_1 + \rho_2 = z$.

Start out with enforcing that the norms are equal: $(\rho_1 + \rho_2) \overline{(\rho_1 + \rho_2)} = \rho_1\overline{\rho_1} + \rho_2\overline{\rho_2} + \rho_1\overline{\rho_2} + \overline{\rho_1}\rho_2 = 2 + 2Re[\rho_1\overline{\rho_2}] = z\overline{z}$

which we can solve for $Re[\rho_1\overline{\rho_2}]$. Of course this is just the cosine of the difference in the angles, $cos(\phi_1 - \phi_2)$. Anyway, plugging in the fact that $\rho_1\overline{\rho_2}$ has also norm $1$, we can then solve for $Im[\rho_1\overline{\rho_2}]$, yielding the full value of $\rho_1\overline{\rho_2}$.

Multiplying the original equation by $\overline{\rho_1}$, we get $1 + \overline{\rho_1}\rho_2= \overline{\rho_1}z$, yielding the $\rho_1 = \overline{z}^{-1}(\rho_1\overline{\rho_2} + 1)$.